# MySQL Query making rows for each joined table row

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT deals.id, 
       deals.partner_id 
FROM   deals 
       LEFT JOIN deals_partners 
              ON ( deals.id = deals_partners.deal_id ) 
WHERE  1 
       AND ( `deals`.`partner_id` = 222 
              OR CASE 
                   WHEN deals.partner_count = 1 THEN 
                   deals_partners.partner_id = 222
                 end ) 
ORDER  BY deals.id ASC
```

I would like to grab the deals that are associated to the partner.

They can either be master of the deal, deals.partner_id = 222 or they can have a row in deals_partners where they get linked to the deal.

The above works out for me, but gives me multiple of the same deals, because of the count of deals_partners I have. I made it a left join, I dont understand why it still keeps grabbing rows from the deals_partners?

Update:

table: **deals**, columns: **ID, title, name, partner_id**

table **deals_partners**, columns: **deal_id, partner_id**

I would like to display the partner 222's deals. To find out which deals, that the partner has, his partner_id can either be in the deal row, in the column partner_id or he can have a row in deals_partners where his partner_id is linked to the deal_id.

Comment: You've lost me at '".$id."'  Can you explain your data structure in more detail?

Comment: Sorry, should be 222 for this example.

Comment: Can you post table structures?

Comment: `A LEFT JOIN B` works the same as `A JOIN B`, except that it makes all fields of B = NULL if no row exists in B for that row in A, so `LEFT JOIN` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

When you join to a table and match on multiple records, you will return multiple records.  You can use the IN clause to prevent this.

```
SELECT deals.id, 
       deals.partner_id 
FROM   deals 

WHERE  `deals`.`partner_id` = 22
       OR id in 
        (SELECT deal_id
         FROM deals_partners
         WHERE partner_id = 222)

ORDER  BY deals.id ASC
```

Comment: Works! , to my knowledge - why exactly "id" IN ?

Comment: I'm just wondering about the performance because of that subquery, unless the subquery is greatly optimised because it's always the same.

Comment: @Karem - You specify "id" in, because you are checking for the existence of the `id` field in the list of all `deal_id`s returned from the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like: (hope it works)

```
SELECT deals.id, 
       deals.partner_id 
FROM   deals 
       LEFT JOIN deals_partners 
              ON deals.id = deals_partners.deal_id AND
                 deals_partners.partner_id = 222
WHERE `deals`.`partner_id` = 222 OR deals_partners.partner_id = 222
ORDER BY deals.id ASC
```

This assumes there is only one match for `deals.id = deals_partners.deal_id AND deals_partners.partner_id = 222`. Otherwise you'll need to add `GROUP BY deals.id, deals.partner_id, deals_partners.partner_id`.